# Batch script to scan subdirectories and delete files that do NOT contain specific word in content

Tags: scripting

I am a novice at best with batch scripts so any help would be greatly appreciated. I have pieced together the following but it's not working exactly as needed. I need it to search a folder and its subdirectories for html files that DO NOT have the name Brian in the contents and automatically delete those files. The biggest problem has been that there are thousands of files and pretty much every one of them have another person's name "Brianne" in them (of course their names have to be so similar, why make it easy). It appears that I have somewhat solved that problem by using SET wordToSearch="<Brian>", however this script doesn't consistently perform the search/delete through all subdirectories, and sometimes deletes everything. If I point pathtofolder directly to each individual folder it does work for that folder alone but this would take forever to do for all the folders. I'm not sure why sometimes it goes through the subdirectories and seemingly stops for some reason, and other times it wipes out every file even if they do contain the word "Brian".

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET pathToFolder="FullPathHere"
SET wordToSearch="\<Brian\>"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F IN ('dir %pathToFolder% /b *.html') DO (
    findstr /IP %wordToSearch% "%pathToFolder%\%%F">nul
    IF !ERRORLEVEL!==1 (
        DEL /Q "%pathToFolder%\%%F"
    )
)
```

I have tried changing the findstr options to /SIP but it still did not go through the subdirectories as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved myself but figured I'd share the working script in case anyone else is searching for something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "targetdir=PathToFolder"
pushd %targetdir%
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b /a-d *.*') do (
 findstr /s /i /p /v "\<brian\>" "%%a" >nul
 if not errorlevel 1 del "%%a"
)
popd
endlocal
```